# erase previous lines canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to create a JavaScript clock using canvas and I have everything on except that the previous lines don't disappear when I draw new ones
I have checked the previous code on similar questions and its  not working  , this is what I have so far , I want to erase previously drawn lines in canvas , it keeps creating new lines one after the other. 
Thanks

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius)
radius = radius * 0.90

setInterval(drawClock, 1000);





function drawClock() {
     drawFace(ctx, radius);
        function drawFace(ctx, radius) {        
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(0, 0,8, 0, 2*Math.PI);
            ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
            ctx.fill();            
        }
        function drawFont(){
            ctx.font = "30px Arial";
            ctx.fillText("12",-17,-140);
            ctx.font = "30px Arial ";
            ctx.fillText("3",140,10);
            ctx.font = "30px Arial";
            ctx.fillText("6",-17,160);
            ctx.font = "30px Arial";
            ctx.fillText("9",-160,10);
            drawFace();

         }
        function drawHands(length, width, color,ang){            
            ctx.save();
            let deg= Math.PI/180;
            ctx.rotate(ang);
            ctx.moveTo(0,0);
            ctx.strokeStyle = color;
            ctx.lineWidth = width;
            ctx.lineTo(0,length);
            ctx.lineCap = 'round'; 
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.restore();
            drawFont();   


        } 
        function getTime(){
            var now = new Date();
            var hour = now.getHours(); 
            var minute = now.getMinutes();
            var second = now.getSeconds();
            // console.log( hour+'::'+ minute + ': '+ second)

            var hours = (hour*Math.PI/6)+
                (minute*Math.PI/(6*60))+
                (second*Math.PI/(360*60));
            var minutes =   minute=(minute*Math.PI/30)+(second*Math.PI/(30*60));
            let seconds=(second*Math.PI/30);


                // drawHands(-90, 5, 'blue', hours);  
                // drawHands(-120, 4, 'red', minutes);    
                drawHands(-150, 2, 'black', seconds);


            console.log(seconds)

            ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

        }

        getTime();
}
```

my html

```
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="350px" height="350px"
                        style="border:8px inset gray; border-radius: 190px;  margin: auto;">

                        </canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to erase the canvas each time you draw. It is best to think of HTML5 Canvas as drawing **one frame at a time**. Therefore, when you draw the next frame, you should clear out the previous frame using `clearRect()`:

```
ctx.clearRect(-canvas.width/2, -canvas.height/2, canvas.width, canvas.height); // x, y, w, h
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/chiss22/pen/wRKJON

Comment: Thanks a lot  Chris , it totally worked.    im grateful.!!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, and most common, solution is to clear the entire canvas and redraw the clock at each step.

```
setInterval(function () {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawClock();
}, 1000);
```

Other notes:

- You only have to set the font once before you begin filling text
- You should move drawFace, drawFont, drawHands, and getTime out of the drawClock function so they are not re-created each time